# Push isn't working on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, push-notification, iphone-6

I have used easyapns for push services in my app. Push is working fine on iOS 8 but my client is saying that push isn't working on iPhone 6. I don't have iPhone 6 to check. Would anyone else encounter this same problem. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that they have notifications disabled for your app in system settings?

Comment: No,Notification is on still he dont receive push.FYI its working fine on iphone 5s ios8 device

Comment: It sounds like a software issue, not a hardware issue. Maybe the app didn't register for notifications properly, or the user accidentally said no to enabling them, and your app didn't respond appropriately to notifications being subsequently enabled in settings.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have working for iOS 8 and iPHONE 6/6+.  iOS 8 changed the way push notification registration works.  The following code will allow the device to register for push notifications on iOS 8 and pre iOS 8 devices.

place this code in your appDelegate.m in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}  else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
#else

UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];

#endif
```

Also, add this as a new method in your appDelegate.m

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif
```

let me know how that works.

Comment: I have alreday did this.Push is working on ios 8 except iphone 6 device.

Comment: I'm working on upgrading an app that was built for ios 5 to be built with ios 9. This code was exactly what I needed!